Is charge an intrinsic property of "all" the fundamental particles or an intrinsic property of "certain" fundamental particles?
Charge is said to be an intrinsic property of particles of which matter is made of. First of all, what does the word "Intrinsic" actually signify in this context?? Does it mean that "charge" accompanies these particles whenever they exist??
Also, Which statement(s) given below are actually correct??
(A) Charge is an intrinsic property of "all" fundamental particles.
(B) Charge is an intrinsic property of "certain" fundamental particles.
(C) Charge is an intrinsic property of "matter".
(Also do the fundamental particles that form matter also include neutrino and boson apart from quarks and electrons??)

Well, all fundamental particles, including even those with charge zero! :)

The way we describe particles in quantum field theory is as states of a quantum field. For example there is an electron field that fills all of space. If we excite this field by adding energy to it that excited state appears as an electron. This neatly explains how particles can be created in colliders. The kinetic energy of the colliding particles goes into exciting the quantum fields and those excitations appear as new particles. It also explains why all electrons are identical i.e. because they are all excitations of the same electron field.
Properties like charge and spin are intrinsic properties of the field. For example all the excitations of the electron field will have charge $-1$ and spin $\tfrac12$. Different fields have different intrinsic properties, e.g. the neutrino field has a zero charge, so the answer to your question is that the charge is an intrinsic property of the field. The particles that we observe get their properties from the field.
You could argue that charge is an intrinsic property of all fields but may have the value zero, so the electron field has charge $-1$ and the neutrino field has charge $0$.

Electrical charge is an intrinsic property of certain particles- not all of them. The ones that are charged are always charged- that is, there is no such thing as an uncharged electron.

I would say that charge is an intrinsic property of all fundamental particles. It's just that neutral particles have charge = 0.

I think it's worth arguing whether we consider Charge to be an intrinsic property of all particles that comprise the matter or not. But I still think that it's better to say that "Charge is an intrinsic property of certain fundamental particles like quarks and electrons but some other particles (like neutrino and boson) don't have this intrinsic property as they have zero charge." More specifically, it's better to say that a black body doesn't have the property of reflectance rather than to say that a black body has the property of reflectance but it's value is zero.

What if the Niels had thought about the fact that the intrinsic electric charge was only determined for free electrons, that the energy release when approaching the nucleus takes place via the stripping of the electric field of the electron and the proton and that the determining forces in the atom are the intrinsic magnetic dipoles of e, p and n? What a simple model.
